# MemSQL - create table as select as CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE

Tags: singlestore

Is it possible in MemSQL to create a table using "create table xxx as select ..." with the created table xxx to be disk based (i.e. CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE)? 
I was not able to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: _I was not able to achieve this._ Well, what did you try?

Comment: Did you try following the docs here: http://docs.memsql.com/docs/create-table#section-create-table-select?

Comment: Thanks, eklhad, I really did but I had found myself in a syntactic trap...

Answer (score 3):

You can specify options for the table including indexes like so:

```
create table c (key using clustered columnstore (a)) as select a,b from t;
```

for more info see http://docs.memsql.com/docs/create-table#section-create-table-select

Comment: Thanks, Jack Chen.